# IF Condition in test class

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me how to get the IF condition covered in test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Code :

```
 public List<wrapperClass> getappointmentList1 (){
           wrapperClass tempObj1 ; 
           List<wrapperClass> aReList1 = new List<wrapperClass>();
                   List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,Name,AccountId,Shipment_Info__c,
                    /*Shipping_Address_Line1__c, //These line are covered
                        Shipping_Address_Line2__c,
                        Shipping_Address_Line3__c,
                        Shipping_City__c,
                        Shipping_State_Province__c,
                        Shipping_Zipcode__c,
                        Shipping_Country__c  */
                        from Opportunity where id=:oppid];
           for(integer i=0; i < opp.size(); i++)
           {
             tempObj1 = new wrapperClass();
             tempObj1.billingAddress= opp[i].Shipment_Info__c;
                               }
             aReList1.add(tempObj1);        

             /* Below code commented by Kiranmai as Shipment Info field is split into multiple fields

             //------- Added by Sumit-----------  
             stringList= new List<String>(); 

             if(aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL && aReList1[0].billingAddress!=''){
                List<String> stringList=(aReList1[0].billingAddress).split(',');
                for(integer i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                   all=all+stringList[i]+'<br/>';
                }
             } */

             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line1__c + '<br/>';
             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line2__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Address_Line3__c + '<br/>';
             } 

             if(opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_City__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + '<br/>';
             }  

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             }

             if(opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=NULL && opp[0].Shipping_Country__c!=''){
                 all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';
             }
            /* all = all + opp[0].Shipping_City__c + ', '+opp[0].Shipping_State_Province__c + ' - ' + opp[0].Shipping_Zipcode__c + '<br/>';
             all = all + opp[0].Shipping_Country__c + '<br/>';*/

             all=all.remove('null');

                /*-----------------------------------*/ 
      return aReList1;  
   }
```

Part of Test class :

```
 InvoiceController.wrapperClass tempObj1 = new InvoiceController.wrapperClass ();
   tempObj1.billingAddress='Complete Address';
    opp.Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37';
    opp.Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills';
    opp.Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus';
    opp.Shipping_City__c='Hyd';
    opp.Shipping_State_Province__c='TS';
    opp.Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081';
    opp.Shipping_Country__c ='India';

  list<InvoiceController.wrapperClass> aReList1 =new list<InvoiceController.wrapperClass>();
   aReList1.add(tempObj1);
```

Comment: Thare are so many if's. can you specify which if exactly is not getting covered?

Comment: Code under all the 'if' is not getting covered ?

Comment: @snehakem:All the IF conditions are not getting covered

Comment: @Animesh:All the IF conditions are not getting covered

Comment: @nikkey are you getting any error after running your test class? i mean does your test class pass? if not please provide the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has this condition

```
aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL
```

But the test data is not populating that field

Comment: :Can u please let me know how should i get that condition .All the IF conditions are not getting covered.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: but @Pepe aReList1[0].billingAddress!=NULL  is in comments hence that should not matter.